# Does MinGW support MFC?

Tags: mfc, mingw

I have developed WinAPI applications using MinGW without problems. Now, can I do the same with MFC?

Comment: Related: [Is VCL or MFC free to use in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595720/is-vcl-or-mfc-free-to-use-in-my-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing here but I think you would need to buy a copy of Visual Studio to get a license to use MFC. MFC is not well known for its portable use of C++ either. If you are familiar with MFC, you might find the learning curve for [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) to be reasonable (which I use with MinGW). The MFC/MinGW route sounds very painful :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. MFC stand for **Microsoft** Foundation Classes and Microsoft isn't good at supporting any other products than theirs.
You may try to compile MFC under MinGW if you have the source but the result is uncertain.

Comment: Not true, Digital Mars has a licensed copy of MFC for their C++ compiler. But it's old.