# Will code's edit control in mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

How is coding for create Edit control object(Cedit class) with Mingw?
I read msdn did used "afxwin.h" but cannot found with MinGw compiler.
It is you showed code as good.

Comment: 1. Post the code you have been working on. 2. Polish your language so that we can understand you.

Comment: Dup for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453389/does-mingw-support-mfc/3453454#3453454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The afxwin.h header is part of the MFC framework. No one has come up with a MinGW version of it. So no, you cannot use it with MinGW. Note that even if you could, you would still need to buy a version of Visual Studio that comes with MFC in order to get a license that would allow you to use MFC.

If I were you, I would look into other GUI frameworks. For example [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (which is much nicer than MFC to begin with; MFC is a legacy framework that most people don't use anymore.)